# MKR 1010 voltage confusion

Tags: voltage, mkr1010

I'm very confused about powering my MKR 1010 on a breadboard. It says use USB, but that is 5.5 V and it specifically says never go above 3.3 V, yet there is a 5 V pin. So what size external power supply do I need and where to attach it? Some sites say anywhere from 3.3 to 7 V and even 12 V????

Comment: Does this Q+A help? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/61006/37523

Answer (score -1):

As per the reference at [Arduino Docs](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/mkr-wifi-1010)! it's nominal input voltage is between 5-7V. But make sure you apply in between 3.3V - 5V. And remember to supply it at power socket and not the 5V port itself.